# Is there a provision to import or publish external swagger json/yaml in bloomreach/hippo cms?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, hippocms

The API is hosted outside the CMS and we have swagger JSON/YAML exported fro the API. Requirement is to publish only swagger documentation/spec in Bloomreach/Hippo cms.

Is there an inbuilt capability to directly import swagger json into Bloomreach/Hippo cms and publish the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry you never got a timely answer here. AFAIK there is no ootb functionality for what you want. You can write code to perform this task, either as a service that polls your api or as a rest endpoint where the data can be pushed to. This will have to be translated to a cms document type.